# How to create a (getter) method with attributes of another class

Tags: java

I have two classes, one is House, which surely has other attributes, but I have included only the one with which I have had problem:

```
public class House {

private Address addressOfHouse;

public House (Address addressOfHouse){
    this.setAddressOfHouse(addressOfHouse);

public Address getAddressOfHouse() {
    return addressOfHouse;
}

public void setAddressOfHouse(Address addressOfHouse) {
    this.addressOfHouse = addressOfHouse;
}
}
```

The other is Address:

```
public class Address {

public String streetName;
public String city;
public int postalCode;

public Address (String streetName, String city, int postalCode){
    this.streetName=streetName;
    this.city=city;
    this.postalCode=postalCode;
}

public String getStreetName() {
    return streetName;
}

public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public int getPostalCode() {
    return postalCode;
}
}
```

When I create an object "house", set an address to it and try to call the method "getAddressofHouse":

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Address address2 = new Address("Y", "Praha", 11000);

    House house2 = new House (address2);

    System.out.println(house2.getAddressOfHouse());
```

It does not give me the address of the house. It gives me this:

```
com.company.Address@7f63425a
```

My problem is to know what I have done wrongly with my setter and getter of the address in the class "House". It is an exercise that I have been doing, and it asks me to have an attribute called "addressOfHouse" with with data type "Address" (the class "Address"). So I suppose that I have to call the address of the house through the method "getAddressOfHouse", but I have been trying it and it has not worked at all. Could you help me with it? If you think that I should put the whole code here, I will do it. I thank you all in advance.

Comment: could you add to the description what it should print?

Comment: Technically: It _does_ give you the address of the house. It just does not print it as you expect.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the getter. You forgot to override `toString()` in `Address`.

Comment: Use Setter way of Dependency Injection principle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`System.out.println(house2.getAddressOfHouse());`

Output

> com.company.Address@7f63425a

This is default implementation of `Object.toString()`.

If you want to see smth more usave, you have to override `public String toString() { }` method in your `Adress` class. E.g.:

```
public String toString() {
    return "Address{" +
            "streetName='" + streetName + '\'' +
            ", city='" + city + '\'' +
            ", postalCode=" + postalCode +
            '}';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a toString() method to the address. If not it will print the reference of the object as the default when you try to print.

See: [toString() doc.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) 
Which I repeat here:

> **public String toString()** Returns a string representation of the
>   object. In general, the toString method returns a string that
>   "textually represents" this object. The result should be a concise but
>   informative representation that is easy for a person to read. It is
>   recommended that all subclasses override this method. The toString
>   method for class Object returns a string consisting of the name of the
>   class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character `@',
>   and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the
>   object. In other words, this method returns a string equal to the
>   value of:
>
> getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
>   Returns: a string representation of the object.